# Hide Media Servers in Network Locations for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, home-networking

I just installed Windows 10 1903 and by default it shows all Media Servers (Upnp ones probably, i.e. all Sonos devices) in the network in the Windows Explorer all prominently in Network locations and in the main tree on the left and I want none of that.

Does anyone how to disable that function and prevent Windows 10 and the Explorer to display any Upnp device / Media Server?

[image]

Comment: There's a couple ways to do this, some more complex than others.  Have you tried right-clicking on each and selecting _Delete/Remove_ (Windows allows this for some media servers, but not sure about all).  The best solution would be to manually disable UPnP all together _(it's a massive security flaw, regardless of which way it's deployed)_ and manually forward the ports required on the router, but Sonos products may not allow this